# spring -- are beans in application context binded to PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer  dynamically?

Tags: java, spring

I want to know if beans in my application context are binded dynamically. Specifically, if I have

```
<bean id="mySpringRemoteService"
      class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
      <property name="serviceInterface"
          value="foo.bar.services.mySpringRemoteService" />
      <property name="serviceUrl" value="${spring.remote.service.url}"/>
 </bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:some.properties"/>
    </bean>
```

if i change the property for the service url in my properties file, will retrieving the bean later reflect this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think it is easy for you to have a try yourself.

The answer is No (Unless behavior of Spring changed in 3.x )

I believe you have to implement runtime update behavior for config files.  Take a look in Apache Commons Configurations.